# query php serialized string blob

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field which stores a serialized php string.  Internally in mysql this field is stored as a blob data type.

Is it possible in pure mysql to query that field for a specific value?

by query i mean that as part of the serialized string there may be a value inside such as "myval=1"; I would like to match this.

Comment: Query for value meaning...?

Comment: Anything is possible. *Show us some code.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `LIKE`

```
SELECt * FROM table_a WHERE blob_value LIKE '%myval=1%';
```